# " No module named build.__main__; 'build' is a package and cannot be directly executed " when doing 'python -m build'

Tags: pip, python-packaging

I was following a tutorial on how to build a Python package, and after installing the package locally using `pip install .` In the project directory.

The next was to `python -m build` in the project directory, but get

> No module named build.__main__; 'build' is a package and cannot be directly executed

I do have a build folder , but not __main__.py file though.

The repo of the project is [here](https://github.com/Akash-k-p/Aadhaar_Extractor.git)

Comment: [*build*](https://pypi.org/project/build/) is a tool that needs to be installed separately.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, a new version of [*build*](https://pypi.org/project/build/) 0.10.0 was released that no longer works like this or has a bug.

For a quick fix simply:

```
pip install 'build<0.10.0'
```

Then everything should work like in your tutorial.

By the way, these links below are my favorite tutorial about how to make a pip installable python package.

- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/
- https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject

Good luck, best, Elmar

Comment: @bue did `pip install build` and then tried, seems to work now . `0.10.0` was the version installed . Thanks

Comment: @blue Do you have a link to a bug report for the bug you are mentioning? I never heard of this. I am not sure recommending to install an older version makes sense. Even OP says they did no need the old version, that it works fine with the latest version.

Comment: @sinoroc  oh gosh i didnt know they're different!  i've installed it from the link i commented and everything just work fine, please can you link me a reference?

Comment: @DemistheAnacronist here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/build/

Comment: Came here totally by accident, but thank you